# In Vue.js, how do you prevent navigation for a subroute?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

The nice thing about `beforeRouteLeave` is that you can prevent navigating away under certain conditions.

I have a setup that uses a subroute to render part of the page. I would like a navigation guard on the subroute to prevent switching to another one if the data is not saved.

```
{
    path: '/customers/view',
    component: ViewCustomerShell,
    children: [
        {path: ':id', name: 'ViewCustomer', component: ViewCustomer}
    ]
},
```

So when I visit `/customers/view/12` and make a change, if they try to load `/customers/view/13`, I want to pop up the usual confirmation and potentially stop navigation. Since `beforeRouteLeave` is not called in this situation, what is the recommended approach for preventing navigation? It seems that watching `$route` would be too late, because then the navigation has already occurred.

Note: As mentioned above, `beforeRouteLeave` is not called in this situation; it doesn't work.

Note: Using `onbeforeunload` doesn't work because it only triggers when the entire page changes.

Answer (score 0):

*I have also posted the same answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41442991/2468508).*

[Dynamic route matching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41442991/2468508) is specifically designed to make different paths or URLs map to the same route or component. Therefor, changing the argument does not technically count as leaving (or changing) the route, therefor `beforeRouteLeave` rightly does not get fired.

**However**, I suggest that one can make the component corresponding to the route responsible for detecting changes in the argument. Basically, whenever the argument changes, record the change then reverse it (hopefully reversal will be fast enough that it gets unnoticed by the user), then ask for confirmation. If user confirms the change, then use your record to "unreverse" the change, but if the user does not confirm, then keep things as they are (do not reverse the reverse).

I have not tested this personally and therefor I do not gurantee it to work, but hopefully it would have cleared up any confusion as to which part of the app is responsible for checking what change.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post is very old. but it was the first one I found when looking for the same problem. 
I have no idea if there is a better solution nowadays but for those who are looking for a solution, I can share mine:

**1. Define a global state**

```
let isRouteChangeBlocked: boolean = false;

export function blockRouteChange(set?: boolean): boolean {
    if (arguments.length == 1) {
        isRouteChangeBlocked = !!set;
        return isRouteChangeBlocked;
    }

    return isRouteChangeBlocked;
}
```

**2. Replace the route function**

```
const originalPush = VueRouter.prototype.push;
VueRouter.prototype.push = function(location: RawLocation) {
    if (blockRouteChange()) {
        if (confirm("Du hast ungespeicherte Änderungen, möchtest du fortfahren?")) {
            blockRouteChange(false);
            return originalPush.call(this, location) as any;
        }
        return;
    }
    return originalPush.call(this, location) as any;
};
```

**3. Set the state**

```
@Watch("note.text")
private noteTextChanged() {
    blockRouteChange(true);
}
```

This does exactly what I want. If nowadays there is a better solution, let me know. You can get the full runnable example here: https://github.com/gabbersepp/dev.to-posts/tree/master/blog-posts/vuejs-avoid-routes/code/example

Answer (score -1):

You could use a `$route` object inside your component to watch if it changes and then raise up the confirmation modal... This will get called whenever your route changes!

```
const Baz = {
  data () {
    return { saved: false }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>baz ({{ saved ? 'saved' : 'not saved' }})<p>
      <button @click="saved = true">save</button>
    </div>
  `,

  watch: {
    '$route': function () {
      if (this.saved || window.confirm('Not saved, are you sure you want to navigate away?')) {
      // do something ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As I mention in the post, beforeRouteLeave doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: As I mention in the post, watching $route would be too late, because then the navigation has already occurred.

Comment: This is still a problem: impossible to prevent internal navigation from a component, any new info?