# vue-router: Preventing routing on argument change

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to confirm leaving not saved form route, and if user declines, to cancel changing the route.

It mostly works with

```
beforeRouteLeave: function (to, from, next) { 
                      if (!confirm('Leaving form')) next(false);
                   }
```

The problem is with route arguments, like `#/form-path?id=5` - changing the `id` argument does not trigger `beforeRouteLeave`.

**Which hook can I use to prevent navigation on argument change?**

Comment: This seems an issue unanswered [before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39900517/1610034).

Comment: The simplest solution would be to change anything you want to trigger the method to be part of the route so /form-path/id

Comment: @vbranden from the first answer, unfortunately it looks like that wouldn't help...

Answer (score 1):

[Dynamic route matching](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html) is specifically designed to make different paths or URLs map to the same route or component. Therefor, changing the argument does not technically count as leaving (or changing) the route, therefor `beforeRouteLeave` rightly does not get fired.

**However**, I suggest that one can make the component corresponding to the route responsible for detecting changes in the argument. Basically, whenever the argument changes, record the change then reverse it (hopefully reversal will be fast enough that it gets unnoticed by the user), then ask for confirmation. If user confirms the change, then use your record to "unreverse" the change, but if the user does not confirm, then keep things as they are (do not reverse the reverse).

I have not tested this personally and therefor I do not gurantee it to work, but hopefully it would have cleared up any confusion as to which part of the app is responsible for checking what change.